# I'm missing a Windows drive - how to recover disk space?

Tags: disk, windows-xp, disk-usage, window

I had installed Windows XP on C:\ drive then install Ubuntu on D:\ drive. After that I had formatted the C:\ drive and reinstalled Window XP on C:. However, now I cannot find my Ubuntu and also its disk space.

I need my D:\ drive space, how can I find it?

Comment: check this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows and this: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Answer (score 0):

Every partition has its own file system. Windows can use NTFS of FAT, but Linux uses its own ext2, ext3 or ext4. Because Windows can't read ext file system you can't easily access your files on Ubuntu partition when running Windows. On other hand Ubuntu does 'understand' NTFS and FAT so you can mount and access Windows partition when in Ubuntu.

When booting your BIOS searches for boot sector on device you are booting from (hard drive). Every operating system sets up its own boot sector when installed. Newer operating systems check when another boot sector is already in place and then make dual boot. That is simple menu to choose OS from.

So if you can't even boot up Ubuntu, Windows has probably written over your Ubuntu boot sector. There is some useful article for this problem: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix